# Show exception created in EF Core repository instead of 500 Error

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core, repository, ef-core-2.0

My goal is to verify if an object's name already exists in my EF Core db, if so: throw a specific error. However, I receive a 500 internal server error.

First I created an index on name in DbContext, including **IsUnique** and some code to catch the exception in the repository.

Can I maybe add something in the controller that says if errorcode == 2601 then throw "the required exception"? Or is there another way to overcome this 500 error? Thanks in advance for the help!

**DbContext**:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
        .HasIndex(c => c.Name)
        .IsUnique();
}
```

**Repository**:

```
public async Task<bool> SaveAsync()
{
    try
    {
        return (await _context.SaveChangesAsync() >= 0);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException dbEx)
    {
        SqlException sqlException = dbEx.InnerException as SqlException;
        if (sqlException.Number == 2601)
        {
            throw new Exception("Name already exists. Please provide a different name.");
        }
        throw new Exception(dbEx.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
Public async Task<IActionResult> AddCar([FromBody] Car car)
    ...
    if (!await _repository.SaveAsync())
    {
        throw new Exception("Fail on save...");
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You can do `catch (DbUpdateException ex) when(ex.InnerException is SqlException se && se.Number == 2601)` but I think program flow by exception is not a great road to travel.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. What would you recommend as a better road? (I am still learning and interested in efficiency)

Comment: I changed my code to: 
catch (DbUpdateException dbEx) when (dbEx.InnerException is SqlException se && se.Number == 2601) { throw new Exception("......"); }    but still get the 500 error. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ASP.Net Core, you can create you own [exception handling middleware](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/).

The error handling middleware class itself may look something like:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate m_next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        m_next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await m_next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        string message = "Something is wrong!";

        if (exception is MyException)
        {
            httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound; // Or whatever status code you want to return
            message = exception.Message; // Or whatever message you want to return
        }

        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            error = message
        });

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

You register in Startup.Configure() as:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I'll dive into this more for understanding it better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change stdoutLogEnabled="false" to true and then check the logs at stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout". The error(s) there might tell you something.
2. Check that you set up right Environment Name using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable as so use correct settings like connection string. On your machine by default you have "Development" environment.
3. You may use Error [Handling middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for showing exceptions like

   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();